# How does bow-shock constitute evidence of a magnetosphere?

Tags: magnetic-fields

Several bodies in the Solar System are possessed of a magnetosphere - Sol, Jupiter, Saturn, Earth to name a few. With these we have the proof of spacecraft/readings from Earth. For exoplanets being discovered lately magnetosphere is apparently reported to exist by virtue of a bow-shock observed from Earth/Earth Orbit.

- How does bow-shock constitute evidence of a magnetosphere? Does it spring from empirical evidence in the Solar System?

As a corollary -

- What is the weakest magnetosphere within the Solar System that may be detected from Earth/Earth Orbit?

Answer (score 1):

The magnetosphere and its affects are easily observed around Earth.  So it isn't too much of a stretch to apply this to other planets.  The bow-shock is created by the funneling of the ionized partials around the magnetosphere and it is a [distinct characteristic of its presence](http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1005/1005.1527.pdf).

The weakest inside the solar system?  I don't know, this technique is primarily used extra-solar.  Any presence of a magnetosphere will create a bow-shock.  However it's intensity depends on the volume and speed (including the body's own rotation) of the particles in the field.  More interesting is what is the weakest that can be detected OUTSIDE our solar system (like [WASP-12](http://www.universetoday.com/85088/and-now-exo-magnetospheres/)).  And it turns out they have to be pretty strong, like Jupiter.

This hypothetically "hot" exoplanet would be located between 1 to 50 AU from an ultraviolet-bright star and it would need to have a fast spin for the resulting magnetospheric activity to be detectable at a distance of 150 light-years from Earth.

What’s more, the [LOw Frequency ARray (LOFAR)](http://www.space.com/14399-giant-lofar-radio-antennas-telescope.html) radio telescope should be sensitive enough to detect aurorae on Jupiter-like exoplanets, even though the exoplanets themselves are invisible to other detection methods.

Answer (score 0):

A bow-shock is by no means exclusive to magnetized planets like the Earth, Jupiter, Saturn or Mercury. Venus, which does not possess an appreciable internal magnetic field, and Mars, which has a crustal (small-scale) magnetic field both interact with the incoming super-sonic and super-Alfvénic solar wind (the stream of charged particles originating from the sun) and possess an upstream bow shock.

Both magnetized and unmagnetized planets pose as obstacles to this high speed flow. In the case of magnetized planets, the interaction is dominated by magnetohydrodynamic forces, while in the case of unmagnetized planets, the interaction is more akin to a supersonic ball shaped bullet.

By terminology, we call the region *carved out* in space due to the planetary obstacle a **magnetosphere**, because downstream of the bow shock, the electromagnetic and hydrodynamic properties of the incoming flow change due to the planetary obstacle.

**How does bow-shock constitute evidence of a magnetosphere? Does it spring from empirical evidence in the Solar System?**

If a bow-shock exists, then it stands to reason from the laws of magnetohydrodynamics that flow properties (both electromagnetic and hydrodynamic) downstream of such a shock are vastly different from flow properties upstream of the shock. And,

YES. There is overwhelming evidence from spacecraft in-situ measurements that almost all planetary obstacles (including comets!) have a upstream bow-shock due to their interaction with the solar wind.

**What is the weakest magnetosphere within the Solar System that may be detected from Earth/Earth Orbit?**

To answer this question, we need to understand *how* we can infer the existence of a magnetosphere. At Jupiter and Saturn (both strongly magnetized and very large) we detect radiation emitted from inside the magnetosphere at a period close to the planetary rotation period. These were the first indicators that the gas giants were magnetized, as the presence of modulated radiation in turn implies the existence of charged particles and an internal magnetic field which rotated at the planetary rotation period.

For smaller planetary obstacles (with weaker internal fields), like comets or asteroids, it is difficult to remotely infer the existence of such fields. This is why the discovery of an internal field at Ganymede (one of Jupiter's moons) was a complete surprise.

Much of what we know about the solar system is from NASA missions like Voyager I and II (which flew by many planets), Ulysses, Galileo, Cassini, Rosetta, Juno to name a few.